# jQuery failes to set CSS width and height in iOS / Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, css, safari

The following JavaScript / jQuery code is part of the jQuery plugin "nested", which creates a gapless grid of 1x1, 2x1, 1x2, 2x2 objects (in my case `div`s with a background-image).

In Safari 9 or earlier and in iOS, however, the absolut-positioned image-divs are not moved to their grid positions after computing everything, instead they are kept at position 0|0, overlapping each other. After console-logging tons of variables, I cornered the problem to those lines of code very early in the computation process:

```
$(this).css({
    'display': display,
    'background-size': 'cover',
    'background-position': 'center',
    'background-image': currImage,
    'position': 'absolute',
    'background-color': '#eeeeee',

    'width': currWidth + 'px',
    'height': currHeight + 'px',

    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'top': $(this).position().top,
    'left': $(this).position().left
});
```

`curWidth` and `curHeight` are calculated from data-attributes, cell-size and aspect ratio on each image-div. This calculation works on all tested browsers identically so everything is fine up to here. The css `width` and `height` value of `$(this)`, however, remains `0px` on Safari or iOS after the above css-assignment. On other browsers, those width- and height-values are correctly assigned. The issue persists when using `$.width()` or `$.height()` instead. The other CSS-properties (like background-image) are assigned correctly in Safari.

It might be of interest, that the container-div's HTML is generated from an AJAX response and therefore dynamically added to the DOM using jQuery.

Strangely, when the plugins resize-function (which simply reruns the exact same process as plugin-initialization) is triggered through windows-resize, all values are assigned correctly and the grid suddenly renders and works in the problematic browsers.

**The chain of event is as follows:**

1. Document Loads
2. $(document).ready -> AJAX call
3. AJAX.complete: Creating image-gallery (container) markup
4. Preloading all images
5. Preloading Finished: Calling nested-plugin (where the above code belongs to) on container

Do you have any idea why Safari 9 and earlier fails at assigning the width and height to the div on plugin-initialization? Thanks in advance for every help!

Comment: Can you check the console and see what errors does it show on Safari?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors...

Comment: May it has to do with the css? What display property are you using?

Comment: The variable `display` contains `"block"`

Comment: Have you tried with table.

Comment: That will not work, since the blocks are not of the same size and the plugin doesn't work this way.